# How to create Hbase table with Regex

Tags: linux, shell, hbase

I hope you can help me on a "simple" shell regex.

For example I have this kind of txt file :

```
Mytable1
cf1
cf2
Mytable2
cf1
Mytable3
cf1
cf2
cf3
```

I'm trying to execute a loop script which will make like :

```
echo -e "create 'Mytable1','cf1','cf2'" | hbase shell -n
echo -e "create 'Mytable2','cf2'" | hbase shell -n
echo -e "create 'Mytable3','cf1','cf2','cf3'" | hbase shell -n
```

Can you help me to understand how to do it ?

Thank you so much

RHEL7.4

Alex

Comment: What is the criteria for matching table name and what for column families? I would recommend change format for something different, for example TSV file, where first column is table name and other are column families. Also remember, that HBase best performs with small number of column families.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I'm trying to list all the tables from Hbase, then describe each table in order to sort out the family column.

My goal is to recreate all the table in another hadoop cluster.

Maybe there is an easier way to perform what I want to do... :)

my steps are :

List all the tables : Each line is a table.

```
echo 'list' | hbase shell | tail -1 | sed -e 's/\,/\n/g' -e 's/\ "//g' -e 's/\["//g' -e 's/\"]//g' -e 's/"//g' | grep -vE "PHX|SYSTEM" > list
```

Then, for each table, I sort out the family column : it gives me the schema file I mentionned above.

```
while read line; do echo "family columns of $line are :" && echo "describe '$line'" | hbase shell -n | awk '{print $3}' | grep -vE "^$|DESCRIPTION" | sed 1d | sed '$d' | sed -e "s/'//g" -e "s/,//g" ;done < list > family_list
```

so the last step is the creation of the table.

Regards

Alex